# Values from a list of of values

Tags: python, list, tuples

I working with SDN and network flows within mininet. I'm able to display flows between to hosts and write it into a file, now I want to output specific information. I want to display all n_bytes values from the file see picture below
[image]
I was thinking about writeing all of these values into a list in Python and the use list operations to display n_bytes,

```
with open("/path/to_myfile","r") as f
    n_bytes_num=[line.strip() for line in f]
    print(n_bytes_num[1]
```

this just prints the whole output of the file shown above. print (n_bytes_num [ 1][ 1] just prints out c.
How would I go by doing this, maybe its more efficient to use tuples and have all these as key_values? Later I was thinking about making the user type which values they want to see with `input()`

Comment: Tangential: You should work on your redacting technique.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe a dictionary (key value pair store is more what you're after) try something like this:

```
info_dict = {info_item.split("=")[0]:info_item.split("=")[1] for info_item in line.split(",")}
```

This does rely on all the info being single line